# Switching between activities in a tab gives error the application has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I am working on android application and I am struck at the below error. Can anybody of you help me out with this error:

When I switch between activities in a tab I was able to do it for 2 times on 3rd time I get the error saying `Sorry...application has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again`.
I tried to take the info from LogCat file below is the information:

```
10-19 03:21:53.794: INFO/dalvikvm(460): threadid=1: stack overflow on call to Lsun/misc/Unsafe;.compareAndSwapInt:ZLJII
10-19 03:21:53.804: INFO/dalvikvm(460):   method requires 24+20+0=44 bytes, fp is 0x4186931c (28 left)
10-19 03:21:53.804: INFO/dalvikvm(460):   expanding stack end (0x41869300 to 0x41869000)
10-19 03:21:53.815: INFO/dalvikvm(460): Shrank stack (to 0x41869300, curFrame is 0x4186bc60)
10-19 03:21:53.844: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(460): Shutting down VM
10-19 03:21:53.854: WARN/dalvikvm(460): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
10-19 03:21:53.984: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(460): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-19 03:21:53.984: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(460): java.lang.StackOverflowError
10-19 03:21:53.984: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(460):     at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.compareAndSetState(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:522)
10-19 03:21:53.984: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(460):     at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync.lock(ReentrantLock.java:182)
10-19 03:21:53.984: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(460):     at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock.lock(ReentrantLock.java:261)
10-19 03:21:53.984: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(460):     at java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList.remove(CopyOnWriteArrayList.java:490)
10-19 03:21:53.984: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(460):     at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.removeOnPreDrawListener(ViewTreeObserver.java:377)
10-19 03:21:53.984: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(460):     at android.widget.TextView.onDraw(TextView.java:3875)
10-19 03:21:53.984: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(460):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6740)
10-19 03:21:53.984: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(460):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1640)
10-19 03:21:53.984: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(460):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
10-19 03:21:53.984: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(460):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6743)
10-19 03:21:53.984: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(460):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1640)
10-19 03:21:53.984: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(460):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
10-19 03:21:53.984: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(460):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6743)
10-19 03:21:53.984: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(460):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
10-19 03:21:53.984: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(460):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1640)
10-19 03:21:53.984: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(460):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
10-19 03:21:53.984: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(460):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1638)
10-19 03:21:53.984: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(460):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
10-19 03:21:53.984: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(460):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6743)
10-19 03:21:53.984: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(460):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
10-19 03:21:53.984: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(460):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1640)
10-19 03:21:53.984: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(460):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
10-19 03:21:53.984: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(460):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1638)
10-19 03:21:53.984: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(460):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
10-19 03:21:53.984: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(460):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6743)
10-19 03:21:53.984: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(460):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
10-19 03:21:53.984: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(460):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1640)
10-19 03:21:53.984: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(460):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
10-19 03:21:53.984: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(460):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1638)
10-19 03:21:53.984: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(460):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
10-19 03:21:53.984: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(460):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6743)
10-19 03:21:53.984: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(460):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
10-19 03:21:53.984: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(460):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1640)
10-19 03:21:53.984: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(460):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
10-19 03:21:53.984: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(460):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1638)
10-19 03:21:53.984: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(460):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
10-19 03:21:53.984: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(460):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6743)
10-19 03:21:53.984: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(460):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
10-19 03:21:53.984: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(460):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1640)
10-19 03:21:53.984: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(460):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
10-19 03:21:53.984: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(460):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1638)
10-19 03:21:53.984: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(460):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
10-19 03:21:53.984: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(460):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6743)
10-19 03:21:53.984: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(460):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
10-19 03:21:53.984: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(460):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1640)
10-19 03:21:53.984: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(460):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
10-19 03:21:53.984: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(460):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1638)
10-19 03:21:53.984: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(460):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
10-19 03:21:53.984: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(460):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6743)
10-19 03:21:53.984: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(460):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
10-19 03:21:53.984: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(460):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1640)
10-19 03:21:53.984: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(460):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
10-19 03:21:53.984: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(460):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1638)
10-19 03:21:53.984: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(460):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
10-19 03:21:53.984: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(460):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6743)
10-19 03:21:53.984: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(460):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
10-19 03:21:53.984: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(460):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1640)
10-19 03:21:53.984: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(460):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
10-19 03:21:53.984: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(460):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1638)
10-19 03:21:53.984: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(460):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
10-19 03:21:53.984: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(460):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1638)
10-19 03:21:53.984: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(460):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
10-19 03:21:53.984: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(460):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6743)
10-19 03:21:53.984: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(460):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
10-19 03:21:53.984: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(460):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1640)
10-19 03:21:53.984: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(460):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
10-19 03:21:53.984: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(460):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1638)
10-19 03:21:53.984: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(460):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
10-19 03:21:53.984: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(460):     at android.view
10-19 03:21:54.265: DEBUG/dalvikvm(460): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 3579 objects / 314384 bytes in 218ms
10-19 03:21:54.335: WARN/ActivityManager(59):   Force finishing activity com.muo.Livegroups/.Main
10-19 03:21:54.984: WARN/ActivityManager(59): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{450548b0 com.muo.Livegroups/.Main}
10-19 03:21:57.244: INFO/Process(460): Sending signal. PID: 460 SIG: 9
10-19 03:21:57.334: INFO/ActivityManager(59): Process com.muo.Livegroups (pid 460) has died.
10-19 03:21:57.364: INFO/WindowManager(59): WIN DEATH: Window{45054b98 com.muo.Livegroups/com.muo.Livegroups.Main paused=false}
10-19 03:21:57.414: WARN/InputManagerService(59): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 460 uid 10036
10-19 03:22:04.183: DEBUG/SntpClient(59): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
10-19 03:22:06.441: WARN/ActivityManager(59): Activity destroy timeout for HistoryRecord{450548b0 com.muo.Livegroups/.Main}
```

I tried to use logcat and got the above information.

Can anybody help me to find the solution I get the error only when I go to different activity on 3rd time. First 2 times it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your UI is too complicated, and you are running out of stack space when trying to render it. Use Hierarchy View and try to reduce the number of layers between the root `View` of your activity and the farthest leaves.